# SQL ID to Int32 - there has to be a quicker way (Swift)

Tags: sqlite, swift, int32

Trying to turn a record ID into an Int32 and ending up with a verbose three line/layer trick to achieve the obvious. There must be a shorter way. Can someone put me out of my misery?

```
var XX = resultSet.stringForColumn("ID")
var XXX = XX.toInt()
recordNumberBack = Int32(XXX!)
```

Comment: SQLite does many conversions automatically, so what happens if you just call `recordNumberBack = resultSet.intForColumn("ID")` ?

Comment: That's assigning a string to an Int32 which it doesn't like. I can put it all in one line like recordNumberBack = Int32(resultSet.stringForColumn("ID").toInt()!) but is there a more compact  way?

Comment: `intForColumn()` returns an `int` which corresponds to `Int32` in Swift, so assigning that to `recordNumberBack` should work. It should use SQLites internal casting from strings to integers.

Comment: That is what I would have thought too.